Can I determine from JavaScript or from the user-agent string if browser is "Developer" version?
Chrome, Mozilla and MS-Edge all have "Developer" versions of their products ... essentially early release versions.
Can I tell from JavaScript if a browser is a "Developer" version?  The "User-Agent" strings do not explicitly say "dev" or "developer".  An on-line database may have that information but I have not been able to find one that does.
Reason: I would like to display diagnostic info if a user is accessing a page using a "Developer" version of a browser.  Our regular users are not able to install "Developer" browser versions.
For clarification, I'm not talking about the browser's Developer / Javascript debugger (F12 or CTRL-SHIFT-I) tools.  I'm talking about special pre-release versions of the browser.  Developers have slightly elevated privileges on corporate laptops which allow them to download and install these versions.  Regular users can't do that.

I use the browserslist package on the server - it's not very up to date to be fair, especially with Firefox versions (currently says 132 for firefox, but 133 has been out for over a week)

Browsers always have developer tools that allow any browser user to inspect HTTP responses and the DOM, run JavaScript, change things, etc.

@Pointy - I think the question is about determining if a user is running the current release or a "developer" (future release) version, i.e. Canary in Chrome terms, or "DEVELOPER" in Firefox terms

@Bravo yes I agree, however I'm wondering why. What difference does it make?

OP states they would like to display diagnostic info if a user is accessing a page using a "Developer" version of a browser - seems a reasonable thing to want

Whenever I test my browser for fingerprinting (e.g., Cover Your Tracks or Browserleaks), the best the test site does at identifying my version comes from the user-agent string, which can be spoofed. If it were possible, I'm sure a fingerprinter would do it.

It depends. If the users can install extensions, it's not possible.

I think I can determine the user ID or a group ID within the application and show the diagnostic info if user is in a "Developer" or "Admin" group.  The problem is that real-world (outside the app) group affiliations regularly change but in-app group memberships are not well maintained.

This sounds like it should have been an edit to the question or a comment (in response to someone?), as it does not answer the question as asked
